# How to deserialize `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` into `XMLGregorianCalendar` using jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

Im deserializing xml into pojos:

```
final JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
final PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
        .allowIfBaseType(XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
        .build();

mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

- Since `XMLGregorianCalendar` is an abstract type I added the `PolymorphicTypeValidator`.
- Since I have no jackson annotations but jaxb annotations im using the `JaxbAnnotationModule`.

When I now try to deserialize a valid xml into my pojo I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1437] (through reference chain: MyObject["date"]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1627)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1377)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._locateTypeId(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:96)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromScalar(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdScalarDeserializer.deserializeWithType(StdScalarDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:147)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4218)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
    at MyObject.test(MyObject.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:130)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

I tried to use custom deserializers but that did not help.
Is there something special I need to do for `XMLGregorianCalendar`?
I have other abstract types which are working fine using the `PolymorphicTypeValidator`

**EDIT**

The following is the POJO generated by JAXB XJC:

```
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.*;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.ObjectLocator;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.util.LocatorUtils;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PartialDate", propOrder = {
        "date",
        "time",
})
public class PartialDate implements Equals2, HashCode2, ToString2 {

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "time")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar time;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.date = value;
    }

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.time = value;
    }

    public boolean equals(ObjectLocator thisLocator, ObjectLocator thatLocator, Object object, EqualsStrategy2 strategy) {
        if ((object == null) || (this.getClass() != object.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        final PartialDate that = ((PartialDate) object);
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar lhsDate;
            lhsDate = this.getDate();
            XMLGregorianCalendar lhsTime;
            lhsTime = that.getTime();

            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "date", lhsDate), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "date", lhsTime), lhsDate, lhsTime, (this.date != null), (that.date != null))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar lhsTime;
            lhsTime = this.getTime();
            XMLGregorianCalendar lhsDate;
            lhsDate = that.getDate();

            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "time", lhsTime), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "time", lhsDate), lhsTime, lhsDate, (this.time != null), (that.time != null))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        final EqualsStrategy2 strategy = JAXBEqualsStrategy.INSTANCE;
        return equals(null, null, object, strategy);
    }

    public int hashCode(ObjectLocator locator, HashCodeStrategy2 strategy) {
        int currentHashCode = 1;
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar theDate;
            theDate = this.getDate();
            currentHashCode = strategy.hashCode(LocatorUtils.property(locator, "date", theDate), currentHashCode, theDate, (this.date != null));
        }
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar theTime;
            theTime = this.getTime();
            currentHashCode = strategy.hashCode(LocatorUtils.property(locator, "time", theTime), currentHashCode, theTime, (this.time != null));
        }
        return currentHashCode;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final HashCodeStrategy2 strategy = JAXBHashCodeStrategy.INSTANCE;
        return this.hashCode(null, strategy);
    }

    public String toString() {
        final ToStringStrategy2 strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        append(null, buffer, strategy);
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public StringBuilder append(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy2 strategy) {
        strategy.appendStart(locator, this, buffer);
        appendFields(locator, buffer, strategy);
        strategy.appendEnd(locator, this, buffer);
        return buffer;
    }

    public StringBuilder appendFields(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy2 strategy) {
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar theDate;
            theDate = this.getDate();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "date", buffer, theDate, (this.date != null));
        }
        {
            XMLGregorianCalendar theTime;
            theTime = this.getTime();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "time", buffer, theTime, (this.time != null));
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
@Test
public void canSerializeToXMLAndDeserializeToPOJO() throws DatatypeConfigurationException, JsonProcessingException {
    final PartialDate partialDate = new PartialDate();
    partialDate.setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar_Test.create());
    partialDate.setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar_Test.create());

    final String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(partialDate);

    System.out.println(serialized);

    final PartialDate deserialized = mapper.readValue(serialized, PartialDate.class);

    assertThat(partialDate).isEqualTo(deserialized);
}
```

Serialized XML:

```
<PartialDate>
  <date>java.util.GregorianCalendar</date>
  <date>1585296330000</date>
  <time>java.util.GregorianCalendar</time>
  <time>1585296330000</time>
</PartialDate>
```

And when deserializing I get the error message postet above.

Using a custom serializer so that the XML looks like that:

```
<PartialDate>
  <date>javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar</date>
  <date>1585296330000</date>
  <time>javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar</time>
  <time>1585296330000</time>
</PartialDate>
```

produces the same error.

Comment: Could you show `XML` payload and `POJO` class? It looks like these two do not fit to each other.

Comment: Added the requested informations.